# Java 3 dimensional data structure

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for a way to store a list of six strings that contain any number of Sting-Double key-value pairs.  For example The six string list would be:

["Joy","anger","Sadness","Surprise","Disgust","Fear"].

The list item "Happy" would then have a list of pairs:

<"Joy",1.00>, <"love",0.98>, etc.

Any help is much appreciated.  I've tried Map> but can't seem to get it right.

This is my exhaustive list

```
MutualInformation::findRelatedWords - scanning for similarwords....
    anger, angry
    anger, irrate
    anger, stupid
    anger, annoy
    anger, frustrate
    disgust, disgust
    disgust, dislike
    disgust, hate
    disgust, sick
    disgust, ill
    fear, fear
    fear, afraid
    fear, frighten
    fear, scare
    fear, terrify
    joy, happiness
    joy, glad
    joy, joy
    joy, good
    joy, love
    joy, like
    sadness, sad
    sadness, hurt
    sadness, sorrow
    sadness, cry
    sadness, bad
    surprise, surprise
    surprise, amazing
    surprise, astonish
    surprise, incredible
    surprise, wonder
```

and this is the output of the Mapped object.  As you can see, it's only saving the last item.

[{anger=[frustrate], disgust=[ill], fear=[terrify], joy=[like], sadness=[bad], surprise=[wonder]}]

The partial code is as follows:

```
Map<String, List<String>> relatedWords = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
while (rs.next())
{
  // assign the results to variables, standardising case as we go
  String rs_emotion = rs.getString("emotion").toLowerCase();
  String rs_word = rs.getString("word").toLowerCase();

  System.out.println("\t\t" + rs_emotion + ", " + rs_word);

  relatedWords.put(rs_emotion, Collections.singletonList(rs_word));
}
```

Comment: *I've tried Map> but can't seem to get it right.* Can you please show us what you've tried and why it's not right?

Comment: You might need to clarify your question. It's not clear how the numeric values fit in, or what they represent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key-value pair that you are looking for can be implemented using a HashMap. As follows:

`Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("joy", 1.00);
map.put("love", 0.98);`

These maps could be then stored in another map as follows:

`Map<String, Map<String, Double>> maps = new HashMap<>();
maps.put("Happy", happyMap);`

To iterate over the resulting happyMap:

`for (Object o : happyMap.entrySet()) {
     Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) o;
     System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());
}`

Comment: okay, that makes sense... are you able to do something like this?  
        Map<String, Map<String, Double>> maps = new HashMap<>();
        maps.put("Happy", put("joy",1.00));  I won't know the value of "Happy" unless I iterate twice, so it'd be nice to do it all in one go

Comment: Glad I helped! No, that is not possible. The method "put" does not return anything and thus nothing will be entered as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Make a map that have a string as key and pair as value:

```
Map<String id, Pair>
```

OR, and this is what i would have done, make 2 Maps:

```
 1. Map<String,String>
 2. Map<String,Dobule>
```

to get the pair you just access the value of the key String "Happiness" at both maps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code example. It is a map that contains maps.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mapOfMap = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
mapOfMap.put("fear", map1);

map1.put("annoy", 1);
map1.put("frustrate", 2);
map1.put("stupid", 3);

Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
mapOfMap.put("surprise", map2);

map2.put("surprise", 4);
map2.put("amazing", 5);

System.out.println(mapOfMap.get("fear").get("stupid")); // prints 3
```